# Como puedo actualizar o renderizar de nuevo un componente con react router dom cuando lo llamo desde el mismo

Tags: reactjs, dom, router

Accedo a un ruta creada con react router por ejemplo  y me funciona bien, pero requiero que estando en el mismo componente cuando vuelva a acceder a esta misma ruta se actualice o renderice nuevamente el componente, ¿como puedo hacer esto?

Estoy utilizando react router dom

esta es la ruta

```
<Route to='/riberalta' component={Noticia}>
```

accedo a esta ruta desde otra otra con un link

```
<Link to='/Riberalta'>Ver noticias de RIberalta</Link>
```

me carga bien y funciona pero ahora requiero estando en este componente poder llamar a su misma ruta pero que se actualice su contenido o renderice nuevamente el componente sin cargar la pagina.

Espero su ayuda. Muchas gracias de ante mano.

Comment: Si ya estas en esa ruta y quieres que se actualice necesitas que tu componente se re-renderice, un componente se re-renderiza si los props o el estado cambia, si estas usando clases serita llamando a `this.setState({estado...})` con los cambios a tu estado, o si estas usando hooks llamando a la funcion que setea el estado. `const [state, setState] = useState()`

Answer (score 0):

**podrías hacer algo como esto**

```
<button onClick={()=>location.reload()}>actualizar</Button>
```

Comment: Por favor, valora el incluir una explicación de porqué tu respuesta es válida y como y porqué debería funcionar este cambio.

Comment: Gracias estimado, en si el problema es el siguiente:

Comment: bueno, básicamente  lo que hace es hacer un reload de toda la pagina pero en una spa no es recomendable hacer esto

Comment: Si exactamente ese es mi problema que no encuentro aun solucion, mi aplicacion en una spa y que añadir el efecto de reload al acceder a la misma ruta donde me encuentro.

Comment: lo solucionaste?